# Get src from td element

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following element:

```
<td>
<div class="myClass" id="grid_ctl00_ctl04_f18036c">
    <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
        <li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
                <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-valueslistvalueid="69118">
                    <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="/ball_yellow.gif">
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</td>
```

I want to take the **src attribute text of the img**, I have the table row,col.

```
for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
     var col = able.rows[i][0];
}
```

*I can use only JaveScript.

Thanks.

Comment: you could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get `img` element within the cell and get `src` property or attribute from element object as per your requirement.

```
// assumes `table` refers to the DOM object of table

for (var i = 1, row; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
     // get src property
     var src = table.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector('img').src;
     // or get attribute value
     var src1 = table.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
}
```

```js
var table = document.getElementById('table');

for (var i = 1, row; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  // get src property
  var src = table.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector('img').src;
  // or get attribute value
  var src1 = table.rows[i].cells[0].querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
  console.log(src);
  console.log(src1);
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="myClass" id="grid_ctl00_ctl04_f18036c">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
          <li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
              <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-valueslistvalueid="69118">
                <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="/ball_yellow.gif">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="myClass" id="grid_ctl00_ctl04_f18036c">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
          <li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
              <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-valueslistvalueid="69118">
                <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="/ball_yellow.gif">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="myClass" id="grid_ctl00_ctl04_f18036c">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
          <li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
              <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-valueslistvalueid="69118">
                <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="/ball_yellow.gif">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="myClass" id="grid_ctl00_ctl04_f18036c">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
          <li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
              <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-valueslistvalueid="69118">
                <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="/ball_yellow.gif">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="myClass" id="grid_ctl00_ctl04_f18036c">
        <ul class="rtUL rtLines">
          <li class="rtLI rtFirst rtLast">
            <div class="rtMid">
              <div style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" data-valueslistvalueid="69118">
                <img title="Medium" alt="Medium" src="/ball_yellow.gif">
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What sets `table` so you can use `table.rows`?

Comment: @cale_b That's a great question to ask OP as that is OPs code.

Answer (score 3):

If your variable col is selecting the correct column, try:

```
var src = col.querySelector('img').getAttribute('src');
```